# Full Click/KeyPress Event with Reactive-banana and SDL

Tags: haskell, sdl, reactive-banana

A full click event is a button down and up, without mouse motion, as far as I know. SDL only gives me Button Up and Down events.

Does [`reactive-banana`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana) have any way to express "key down and then key up"?

Incidentally, if I want to have an event that says "key still down", I have to enable SDL's `enableKeyRepeat` so the keyDown event is fired again. How would that be expressed correctly in FRP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

Define a utility function (untested):

```
successive :: (a -> a -> Maybe b) -> Event t a -> Event t b
successive f e = filterJust (b <@> e)
  where b = stepper (const Nothing) (f <$> e)
```

and then use something like

```
successive (\previous current -> if previous == buttonDown && current == buttonUp
                                   then Just ()
                                   else Nothing)
           buttonEvents
```

(pseudo-code because I'm not familiar with SDL).

This should work because behaviours update fractionally after events fire.

Comment: Would that only work if these Events are right after each other, without one in between?

Comment: Yes. You can use `filterE` to filter out events that shouldn't affect click-detection if you need to.

Comment: `previous` is the value that was passed in the immediately preceeding event, and `current` is the value that is passed in the current event.